# VBA do loop , Array and ifs

Tags: vba

I have code that does what I need apart from filling the array.

I have an issue with VBA code I'm accessing mainframes. I need to store a 19 digit number in an array if I find "999" in a facility number "sBuffer". I also need to change the page if line 23 <> "*** END OF ACCOUNTS ***"

```vb
Public Function SearchBCArr() As String
    Dim nrow As Integer
    Dim sCardbill(0 To 4) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim item As String
    Dim sBuffer As String
    Dim nResult As Integer
    
    With Parent
        nrow = 8
        sBuffer = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 3))

        Do Until Len(sBuffer) = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 2, 23) = "*** END OF ACCOUNTS ***")
            ' change page  
            If nrow > 23 Then
                .SendFunctionKey (6)
                nrow = 8
                sBuffer = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 3))
            End If
            'search facility number for 999
            If sBuffer = "999" Then
                item = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 19))
                sCardbill(i) = item
            Else
                'WIB
            End If
            
            Inc nrow
            sBuffer = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 3))
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem/question is?

Comment: `Len(sBuffer) = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 2, 23) = "*** END OF ACCOUNTS ***")`: the left hand size is an integer (length of a buffer), but the right hand side is 'trimming' a boolean, because gettext(...)=astring would result in true or false.

Comment: Thanks, I can change that to <> 000. Also the problem is that array 0 gets filled but the next number goes to array 0 as well. I tried to use a for loop but I need to check for the 999. Do you think I need to split the function?

Answer (score 0):

tinazmu noticed the issue with Len(Sbuffer), thank you.

I also need to add a count for the array i = i + 1 and to redim the array to i

Thank you for everyone that commented, it helped me to go through and think about my code and see the errors.

```
Public Function SearchBCArr() As String
Dim nrow As Integer
Dim sCardbill(0 To 3) As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim item As String
Dim sBuffer As String
Dim nResult As Integer
**ReDim sCardbill(i)**
With Parent
    nrow = 8
    sBuffer = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 3))
        **Do Until Trim(.GetText(nrow, 2, 23) = "*** END OF ACCOUNTS ***")**
            If nrow > 23 Then
                .SendFunctionKey (6)
                nrow = 8
                sBuffer = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 3))
            End If
            If sBuffer = "999" Then
                item = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 19))
                sCardbill(i) = item
                **i = i + 1**
            Else
                'WIB
            End If
            Inc nrow
            sBuffer = Trim(.GetText(nrow, 8, 3))
        Loop
End With
```

End Function